# Transfer of Resources ARN to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, terraform

I have Lambda written in Golang. Lambda does some action and invoke Step Function. I have hard coded Step Function ARN in the code. I don't like this solution and would like to improve it. How it works right now:

```golang
arn := aws.String(sfnArn) // e.g: arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123:stateMachine:machine-name
params := &sfn.StartExecutionInput{Input: input, Name: name, StateMachineArn: arn}

output, err := client.StartExecution(params)
```

Any idea how to improve it? I'm using Terraform so maybe there is any option to pass ARN through TF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options how to solve this issue. So I am going to name the once that come to my mind with focus of leveraging AWS services.

1. **SSM**: save the ARN of the Step Function in the [SSM parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) and read this parameter when your Lambda runs using the [ssm.GetParameter()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ssm#Client.GetParameter) API.
2. **Lambda environment variable**: You can set the ARN as environment variable to your Lambda and use [os.GetEnv()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) or [os.LookupEnv()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv).
3. **Resource Tags**: You can give your Step Function a tag that is unique to it and then use the [resourcegroupstaggingapi.GetResources()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/resourcegroupstaggingapi#Client.GetResources) API to get the Step Function and then read the ARN from that resource in your code.

There are obviously a million more options. You could read a configuration file from S3 or EFS or bundle a static configuration file with your Lambda or query HTTP based API to read that value.